# Read Excel File Data From HttpPostedFileBase object

Tags: excel

Uploaded Excel file Is In HttpPostedFileBase object

**HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files["ExcelFileeUploader"];**

Want To Read Excel Data From This Object. thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), it's as simple as this:

```
public void ImportExcelXls(HttpPostedFileBase fileBase)
{
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(fileBase.InputStream))
    {
        // get the first worksheet in the workbook
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        int col = 1;

        for (int row = 1; worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value != null; row++)
        {
            // do something with worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value                    
        }
    } // the using 
}
```

Comment: http://rajandmello.blogspot.com/2010/07/get-excel-data-by-passing-file-stream.html

Comment: In my environment it throws `"A disk error occurred during a write operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8003001D (STG_E_WRITEFAULT))"` error on second form submit.

Comment: I didnt wanted to use a plugin, but i did not find any other good way. So i installed  EPPlus and it's great! and very simple. Thanks!.